# Create and rename files

Tags: c#, asp.net

My file can be save properly in the backup found. I would like to rename the backup file name,something like `"DEPOT-Pub_Sub_Combined (wo CardHolder)" + textbox1.text + ".sql"`. For example the `textbox1` value is 1,So it will be `DEPOT-Pub_Sub_Combined (wo CardHolder) 1.sql` and when I run the program 2nd time, It will create copy of the original backup and update that file and save It's name as whatever the `textbox.text value is`. How can this be done? what should i do?

```
private void modifySQLFile()
{
    CopyFile();
   string destFileName = @"backup\DEPOT-Pub_Sub_Combined (wo CardHolder).sql" ;
   string[] fileTexts = File.ReadAllLines(@"backup\DEPOT-Pub_Sub_Combined (wo CardHolder).sql");
   int counter = 0;

    //File processing 
    foreach (string line in fileTexts)
    {
        //only process non-comments line
        if (line.StartsWith("--") == false)
        {
            //replace instances of server name
            if (line.Contains(SERVERNAME) == true)
            {
                fileTexts[counter] = fileTexts[counter].Replace(SERVERNAME, textBox1.Text);            
            }

            if (line.Contains(ACCESSID) == true)
            {
                fileTexts[counter] = fileTexts[counter].Replace(ACCESSID, textBox2.Text);
            }

            if(line.Contains(NETWORKID) == true)
            {
                fileTexts[counter] = fileTexts[counter].Replace(NETWORKID, textBox2.Text);
            }


        }
        counter++;
    }
    //update file
    File.WriteAllLines(destFileName, fileTexts);
File.Move(destFileName, "DEPOT-Pub_Sub_Combined (wo CardHolder)" + textBox1.Text + ".sql");
    MessageBox.Show("Completed!");
}

private void CopyFile()
{

    string targetPath = @"backup";
    string destFile = Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);

    if(!Directory.Exists(targetPath))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
    }

   File.Copy(fileName, destFile, true);
}
```

Comment: your code looks like it is doing what you describe in your question. The only thing that I miss is the creation of the backup filename like in your description. Where do you initialize `fileName` from your `CopyFile` method? What exactly are you still having problems with?

Comment: Hi Mong Zhu, my problem now is, the files are created. But when it creates the copies it does not goes into the backup folder.

Comment: it still remains to clarify how `fileName` is created. Might it be that you overwrite the file in the backup folder instead of creating new ones? or did not a single file made it into the folder?

Comment: 'fileName' i created as a public string. 
string fileName = "DEPOT-Pub_Sub_Combined (wo CardHolder).sql";

Comment: ok when I try your `CopyFile` method it works as intended. It copies the file to the folder. Since the overwrite property in the call of `File.Copy(fileName, destFile, true);` is set to true I get the feeling that your filename is not changing and you overwrite the old one

Comment: doesn't it has to change according to the entry of the textbox as you wrote in your question?

Comment: I need those copies file to be the back up .. for example the file name DEPOT-Pub_Sub_Combined (wo CardHolder) 1 .sql" and DEPOT-Pub_Sub_Combined (wo CardHolder) 2.sql"; and DEPOT-Pub_Sub_Combined (wo CardHolder) 3.sql"; all this 3 files will be created and should be inside the backup folder i created. Now this 3 files is not in the backup folder, its outside of the backup folder. Im not sure where have i do wrong. I updated my codes already

Comment: You load the original file from the backup folder change it and save it with a the same name inside the backup folder. with `File.Move(destFileName, "DEPOT-Pub_Sub_Combined (wo CardHolder)" + textBox1.Text + ".sql");` you copy the new file outside the backup folder. The second argument is the destination the first one is the source!

Comment: have you tried the solution that I suggested?

Comment: Yes i tried. Does not work. Does not have multiple files and the filename does not include the textbox1.text value..

Comment: it just mainly overwrite the file

Comment: actually it does include the textbox: `// make a new filename each time this method is executed
    string newFileName = @"DEPOT-Pub_Sub_Combined (wo CardHolder)" + textbox1.text + ".sql"
    // give it as parameter so that the copied file gets a new name
    CopyFile(newFileName);`

Comment: Okay, thank you. My problem is solve already. I got what i want. Thank you so much

Comment: how did you solve it? it would be good to know for the people who encounter in future the same problem, so that they can find also a solution

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the "File.Move" method.

[See more at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.file.move(v=vs.110).aspx)

In your example it would be:

```
File.Move(fileName, "DEPOT-Pub_Sub_Combined (wo CardHolder)" + textbox1.text + ".sql");
```

Greetz,
Jordan Kniest

Comment: I tried this method, it did create the file, but it does not copy into the backup folder.

Answer (score 0):

try this please :

```
private void modifySQLFile()
{
    // make a new filename each time this method is executed
    string newFileName = @"DEPOT-Pub_Sub_Combined (wo CardHolder)" + textbox1.text + ".sql"
    // give it as parameter so that the copied file gets a new name
    CopyFile(newFileName);

    string destFileName = @"backup\DEPOT-Pub_Sub_Combined (wo CardHolder).sql" ;
    string[] fileTexts = File.ReadAllLines(@"backup\DEPOT-Pub_Sub_Combined (wo CardHolder).sql");
   int counter = 0;

    //File processing 
    foreach (string line in fileTexts)
    {
        //only process non-comments line
        if (line.StartsWith("--") == false)
        {
            //replace instances of server name
            if (line.Contains(SERVERNAME) == true)
            {
                fileTexts[counter] = fileTexts[counter].Replace(SERVERNAME, textBox1.Text);            
            }

            if (line.Contains(ACCESSID) == true)
            {
                fileTexts[counter] = fileTexts[counter].Replace(ACCESSID, textBox2.Text);
            }

            if(line.Contains(NETWORKID) == true)
            {
                fileTexts[counter] = fileTexts[counter].Replace(NETWORKID, textBox2.Text);
            }


        }
        counter++;
    }
    //update file
    File.WriteAllLines(destFileName, fileTexts);
    MessageBox.Show("Completed!");
}

// the new filename should go for the copy
private void CopyFile(string newFileName)
{

    string targetPath = @"backup";
    string destFile = Path.Combine(targetPath, newFileName);

    if(!Directory.Exists(targetPath))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
    }

   File.Copy(fileName, destFile, true);
}
```